# Angular Material: Prevent Slider from Overlapping with Menu

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am just getting started with Angular Material and experiencing the problem that the slider component overlaps with my menu. 
[image]

How can I make sure the slider is displayed below the menu - is there some non-overlapping flag I can set to accomplish this?

May html code looks like this:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="aboveMenu">Above</button>
<mat-menu #aboveMenu="matMenu" yPosition="above">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>

<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="belowMenu">Below</button>
<mat-menu #belowMenu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" yPosition="below">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>

<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="beforeMenu">Before</button>
<mat-menu #beforeMenu="matMenu" xPosition="before">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>

<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="afterMenu">After</button>
<mat-menu #afterMenu="matMenu" xPosition="after">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>

<mat-slider min="1" max="100" step="1" value="1"></mat-slider>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Best regards, Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use `flex-wrap` in your styles this way:

```
display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Here is a simple snippet adding it as an inline style but I do suggest that you **add them in a separate file and reference the divs with classes**.

I hope It helps you!

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div style="width: 100%;">
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="aboveMenu">Above</button>
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="belowMenu">Below</button>
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="beforeMenu">Before</button>
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="afterMenu">After</button>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%;">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50">
  </div>
</div>
```

More information about flex and flex-wrap:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Comment: Than you very much this really helped!

Comment: Glad to hear that!